# Force OSX to switch to the wifi access point with the strongest signal

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have two wifi hotspots set up. Comcast X1 Router (Wireless Gateway 1) and an Airport Extreme. Both networks are set up with the same SSID, passphrase, and WPA2 Personal.

Unfortunately, the wifi switch seems to work only in one direction. Initially I will be connected to the Airport extreme, as I get in range of the Comcast Router my Macbook (and iPhone) automatically switch to the stronger signal. When I move back to the airport extreme I stay connected to the Comcast box with inferior signal strength. I verified the signal strength with Wifi Explorer.

Turning the wifi on and off when close to the Airport Extreme will reconnect me to the Airport Extreme.

Comment: You can do this in bash (many ways). Let me know if it is a pressing issue and I'll help you out.  It is possible though so you can always just research it yourself as well.

Comment: Would love some help on this. Google search didn't surface anything about writing bash scripts to join the strongest hotspot

Comment: I would give up on this (I tried a lot with a similar setup to no avail) and get a mesh network like Eero or Luna, imho.